# Combine two gulpif into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
     return getEnvScriptsStream()
        .pipe(gulpif(stgOrProd(), uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif(stgOrProd(), concat('embed')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

How can I combine the two `gulpif()` into one?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is with [lazypipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazypipe) as per the [`gulp-if` documentation itself](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if#works-great-with-lazypipe):

> Lazypipe creates a function that initializes the pipe chain on use. This allows you to create a chain of events inside the gulp-if condition.

For the example in question:

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
  return getEnvScriptsStream()
    .pipe(gulpif(stgOrProd(), lazypipe().pipe(uglify).pipe(concat, 'embed')()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think gulp plugins are object streams so you might be able to get away with

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
     return getEnvScriptsStream()
        .pipe(gulpif(stgOrProd(), uglify().pipe(concat('embed'))))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation about this. I tested it and it seems to work but not all of the time. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean sometimes? Any specific errors? If you want to understand better conceptually [how gulp works](https://medium.com/@contrahacks/gulp-3828e8126466) I recommend substack's [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) to learn about streams. Gulp plugins are object streams where the objects are something called vinyl objects, which are mainly an abstraction of a file. The most common instance of this is what the vinyl-fs module implements.

Comment: concat uses the through module and uglify the through2 one. That might [cause some trouble](http://r.va.gg/2014/06/why-i-dont-use-nodes-core-stream-module.html)